# A simple way to get the cross section of a sphere.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, cross-sections

I'd like to cut the $3$-sphere of radius $1$ with the plane $x+y+z=k$.
Of course the cross-section is a circle: the problem is that I'd like to have the equation of the circle expressed by two "coordinates" on the plane.

An orthogonal basis for the plane (better, of the linear subspace associated to it) is $\{u_1,u_2\}$ where $u_1=1/\sqrt{2}(1,-1,0)$ and $u_2=\sqrt{2/3}(1/2,1/2,-1)$ (obtained by Gram-Schmidt).

Having a point $P$ on the intersection between the sphere and the plane, I could get the coordinates $X,Y$ on the plane simply by inner product with the basis vectors: $X=\langle P,u_1\rangle$ and $Y=\langle P,u_2\rangle$.

The calculations appear to be horrible: is there a neat way to do it?

The problem is not really limited to a sphere: i'd be interested in the general case of a generic surface cut by the same particular plane.

Comment: It seems as if you want to parametrise the sphere with two variables. This cannot be done globally.

Comment: No, I'm only interested in the cross-section, that is, a circle.

Comment: Ah I see, I still find reading to be difficult. Well you could try finding the normal $n$ to the plane in which the circle lies, then two spanning orthonormal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ of the plane in which the circle lies, and then $n+v_1\cos\theta+v_2\sin\theta$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ is a parametrisation (or at least it's close, this was off the top of my head).

Comment: Please read my post: I am doing just that. The question is whether there is a simple way out of the tedious calculations.

Comment: I don't think these are tedious calculations. What's so tedious? It's just a normal and a basis and then you are done.

Comment: I fear you did not get the point of the question: I'm searching for an equation in the new variables $X,Y$. I know the solution in the particular case of the sphere, that is $X^2+Y^2=1−k^2/2$.

Comment: Construct a rotation matrix that rotates $u_1$ to $x$ axis, $v_1$ to $y$ axis, and plane normal (their cross product) to $z$ axis. (Since pure rotation matrices are orthogonal, their transpose is their inverse, and you just need to those three unit vectors as row vectors to get that rotation matrix.) If you then transform the equation of the surface (here unit sphere, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$), you have the parametric form for each intersection, $z = k$.

Comment: Errata corrige: the solution should be $X^2+Y^2=1-k^2/3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two equations: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y+z=k$. The coordinates here relate to your new coordinates as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{1/2} & \sqrt{1/6} & \sqrt{1/3} \\
-\sqrt{1/2} & \sqrt{1/6} & \sqrt{1/3} \\
0 & -\sqrt{2/3} & \sqrt{1/3}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\\Z\end{pmatrix}$$

The first two columns are your $u_1$ and $u_2$, the last is the normal vector of the plane. Now use this to express your equations in the new coordinates. Since the matrix describes just a rotation (or since your new basis is still orthonormal), the sphere still has $X^2+Y^2+Z^2=1$. For the plane, you multiply the row vector $(1,1,1)$ (which is the normal vector of the plane) from the left to the matrix, or in other words, you add the rows and obtain $\sqrt3Z=k$. Now you can combine these two equations and eliminate $Z$ from them. One approach would be computing the resultant using the Sylvester matrix:

\begin{align*}
1Z^2 + 0Z + (X^2+Y^2-1) &= 0 \\
\sqrt3Z - k &= 0
\\
0=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & (X^2+Y^2-1) \\
\sqrt3 & -k & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt3 & -k
\end{vmatrix}&=k^2+3(X^2+Y^2-1)
\end{align*}

So that's your implicit equation for the intersection figure. You could look at this and see that it's a circle, and then parametrize it using trigonometric functions of a single parameter if you like.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your answer, nevertheless I don't understand why the resultant should give the correct function. could you please point me to some further information?

Comment: @marcotrevi: The resultant of two univariate polynomials is zero if they have a common zero. So here I treat both equations as polynomials in $Z$. If the resulting polynomial equals zero, then for those choices of variables there exists a $Z$ which satisfies both equations. I've reduced two equations in four indeterminates to a single equation in three indeterminates, eliminating $Z$. Of course, since the equation of the plane is so easy, I could just have solved that for $Z$ (yielding $Z=k/\sqrt3$) and substituted that into the sphere equation to get $X^2+Y^2+k^2/3=1$ which is equivalent.

Comment: Crystal clear. Thank you!